# Document library - problem with document link

Tags: document-library, content-type, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a database of files, which will mostly contain *.zip packages with SCORM. This packages will be stored in the remote location and I'd like to provide only links to them. SharePoints document library allows me that since I can hook "Document Link" Content Type to it. The thing is, that when I add new document link, there is an aspx page generated behind the scenes which provide code for redirecting to file in the remote location. Unfortunately, that is not what I want, so I'm looking for a way to take the user directly to the location where the package is (without any SharePoint redirection magic). SharePoint Learning Kit which I want to use to consume those packages doesn't follow this redirection.

Have You ever done that and/or have any idea how could I achieve what I want? Is it even possible?

Comment: Are your remote files stored inside or outside of SharePoint, ie are they in a document library on another site, or some other document management system?

Comment: I tried this with files stored in remote www server. I haven't tried with sharepoint document library, but that would definitely satisfy my needs.